# Javascript won't work on Html server control?

Tags: asp.net, html, servercontrol

I am writing a website with `ASP.Net`.

I will have lots of `html generic controls` like `<div> <span>` and so on..

I have some `onclick` javascript functions, `onmouseover` javascript functions..

They are working fine..

Then I need to control them on the server side.

So, I add `runat="server"`..

After that, all the javascripts aren't working anymore..

I understand they aren't working coz all the events are now going back to server side.

So, is there anyway to make them work??

For eg,

```
<div id="myDiv1" onclick="myfunction(para1)"><img src="..." /></div>
```

the above code is working..

```
<div id="myDiv1" runat="server" onclick="myfunction(para1)"><img src="..." /></div>
```

the above code is not working...

I can make it work, probably by

```
<div id="externalDiv1" onclick="myfunction(para1)"><div id="myDiv1" runat="server" ><img src="..." /></div></div>
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Code? What you're suggesting doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What does the javascript look like that's not working?

Comment: well.. javascript is to change the class of css of the <img> inside its tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-side or client-side controls makes no difference as far as javascript is concerned. ALL server-side controls end up being rendered as normal HTML controls. If your javascript functions are not working might be because you are accessing them by the wrong id since by making them server-side controls they can now have ids that follow a pattern like `<parent_id>_<control_id>`.

For example, a span element declared like this:

```
<span id="mylabel" runat="server"> testing</span>
```

may end up being rendered as:

```
<span id="MainContent_mylabel"> testing</span>
```

ASP.NET 4.0 has a feature called `CliendIDMode` which can be set to [`static`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), meaning, that your ids on the markup will stay unchanged after the page is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you used document.getElementById() to get an element by its id. If you are using master pages, the IDs of server controls will be changed after rendering to the page, in that case, you have to use its ClientID
for e.g.

```
var myDiv1 = document.getElementById("<%= myDiv1.ClientID %>");
```